# google spreadsheet formula to concatenate horizontally

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

i have 2 columns: column A with ids and column B with categories
i'm trying to concatenate the categories with the same id into a single cell, like in this spreadhsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13yFjluXDGBhSyfo_4pRcv6RrDrgYkJM6goCOGtrurH8/edit?usp=sharing

how can i do that?
thanks!

i tried this but it is not working
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,
QUERY($B$2:$B$1000,
"SELECT C WHERE A = "&A2:A)),
""))

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(countif(A2:Σ,Σ)=1,join(", ",filter(B:B,A:A=Σ)),))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it on the mk_help tab.

```
=MAP(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A),LAMBDA(id,IF(id="",,{id,JOIN(", ",FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=id))})))
```